# Translation: 多大の貢献をなし他の範とするところ

Tags: grammar, business-japanese

I'm trying to translate accurately the following text (JP > EN)...

I'm particularly puzzled about the part: "**多大の貢献をなし他の範とするところ**". Did I understand the meaning well? Does "他の範" refer to other departments in the company?

> 表彰状
>   貴部所は建築工事表彰内規に基づき平成二十八年度建築工事中総合成績が極めて優秀であって会社の技術水準並びに業績の向上に**多大の貢献をなし他の範とするところ**甚大であると認められるので兹に所員一同の功績に対し表彰金を贈り表彰します。

### My English translation:

Certificate of Distinction

In light of the superior and all-round excellence of your department’s achievements in 2016 in the domain of construction work, which has brought about major contributions to the improvement of our company’s technological abilities and performance, **unparalleled in other sectors**, and on the basis of our company’s internal regulations as regards commendations, I hereby present your department with this certificate and its corresponding financial award in recognition of the achievements of all department members.

Comment: Which part did you translate to "unparalleled"? `Does "他の範" refer to other departments in the company?` No, just 「他」 refers to other departments in the company. 「範」 means "example, model".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you excerpted crosses the boundary of phrasing. It's actually,

> 会社の技術水準並びに業績の向上に**多大の貢献をなし** / **他の範とするところ**甚大である

While the first portion aptly corresponds with your translation:

> *...has brought about major contributions to the improvement of our company’s technological abilities and performance...*

the real problem is in the second portion.

> 他の範とするところ甚大である

This wording utilizes a relatively rare as well as ceremonious construction. ところ seen here is a literal translation of [the (Classical) Chinese relative particle 所](https://www.chineseboost.com/grammar/suo-structural-particle/) (for grammatical details please see the link), that, in short, makes `AのVところ` mean "what A V". Thus,

> 他の範とするところ甚大である
>   = "what others (can) take as model is huge"
>   ≈ *from what others (can) learn is huge*
>   ≈ *(you) set a profound example to others*

Comment: You are absolutely right about the parsing problem I had. This ところ, especially, felt really weird — I had no idea that it actually stood for the Chinese 所 that you mention, which is brilliant! (I guess it would be something like "为其他部门而言，贵部门**所**树立的榜样是良好的" ... though a real Chinese phrase would be much simpler than that of course). Thank you.

Comment: @killer_rabbit Because it mingles with Japanese words... Originally it was used to translate phrases like 為人所欺 into 人の欺くところと為る. The as-literal-as-possible back-translation of this clause to Classical Chinese would be like "他人所（以）取範者甚大".

Answer (score 1):

Try something like "and serves as/has set a tremendous example for the other departments" for the 他の範とするところ甚大である part.

Breaking it down a little:

- 他の範 → a good model/example for others
- とするところ → the element/aspect of serving as/setting, the way it acts/serves as
- 甚大である → great, enormous, tremendous

The rest looks pretty good, although strictly speaking, the Japanese text says "technological *level*/standard and performance" rather than *abilities*, but your version is perfectly possible in the broader context.

Even for a certificate like this, that's impressively formal and stilted language, though. I get a vision of the person presenting it stumbling over 兹に while reading it during the award ceremony! :)

Comment: Many thanks, Philippe. You might be right about the "technological level/standard" part, too... And yes, this 兹に is simply delightful!

Answer (score 0):

> Does "他の範" refer to other departments in the company?

Yes.

「会社」の中の「貴**部所**」なので、「**他**の範」の「他」は「**他**部所」を意味します。
表彰を受ける「**所**員」は「貴部**所**」の「**所員**」です。

一般には「部所」とは言わず「部署」と言いますが、この会社の組織構成が「＊＊＊部」と「＊＊＊所」が同格で存在しているものと思われます。すなわち、この会社では、研究所、事業所のように部署名の最後に「所」が付く部署と、営業部、人事部、経理部のように部署名の最後に「部」が付く部署が併存しているものと思われます。「部所」は「部ならびに所」を表し、一般にいう「部署」を指しているものと思われます。
一般には貴部署、他部署というと*your department* and *the other department* in the companyですが、この会社では「＊＊所」も「＊＊部」も一般にいう「部署 *department*」と考えてよいと思います。
今回表彰を受ける部署の従業員は、「所員」と呼ばれていますので、研究所、事業所のように部署名の最後に「所」が付く部署の従業員です。

Comment: 非常に詳しく有益な答えありがとうございます！（＾⊆＾）

Answer (score 0):

「他**の**範とするところ甚大である」 means 「他（の部署・人たち）**が**｛お手本にする（べき）ところが大きい / 見習う（べき）ところがたくさんある｝」, "*lit.* (The department) has a lot for the other departments to follow", i.e. "(The department) is a good example for others to follow". The の in 他の marks the subject for the verb phrase 範とする ("to follow someone's example").